# How to perform a two-way mixed ANOVA with three groups, three time points and one dependent variable in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, group-by, multiple-columns, anova, mixed-models

I have extracted time series from a few regions of interest in the brain (fMRI) and I have added pairwise correlation (Fisher-Z) values for each subject under columns corresponding the correlation between two nodes in the brain (for example: stim_lvis3,  stim = stimulation site and lvis3= left visual network 3). Now, I would like to perform ANOVAs on this dataset to look at the effects and between/within group differences (3 groups x 3 timepoints). My data is already in long format.

*groups= ctbs [10 subjects x 3 timepoints], itbs = [10 subjects x 3 timepoints], and sham [10 subjects x 3 timepoints]

1. Any suggestions on how this can be done, given that I have 12 columns with connectivity values (stim_lvis3....stim_rpcc1). for example I have not been able to box plot the data faceted both by time and group?
2. How to perform a two-way mixed anova in this situation for all 12 columns for each group at a specific timepoints and then compare groups at each timepoint?

[image: data in long format]

I converted subject, time and group to factors

```
tbs %>%
  group_by(time, group) %>%
  get_summary_stats(stim_lVis3, type = "mean_sd")
```

> Error in tbs(.) : could not find function "tbs"

```
bxp <- ggboxplot(
  tbs, x = "time", y = "stim_lvis3",
  color = "group", palette = "jco"
)

bxp
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'stim_lvis3' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! It's looks like you're new, but in the future to get great answers quickly, make sure you include sample data in a format that useable (i.e., the output from `dput(head(myData))`). Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

I know of two approaches to completing within and between ANOVA. The easier to implement version is from the package `ez`. The package `jmv` offers a much more complex write-up but you have an immense amount of control, as well. I'm sure there is more to `ez`'s version, but I haven't worked with that package very much.

I created data to somewhat simulate what you are working with.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jmv)
library(ez)

set.seed(35)
df1 <- data.frame(subject = factor(rep(1:15, each = 3)),
                  time = factor(rep(c(1:3), 15)),
                  group = factor(rep(1:3, each = 15)),
                  stim_IVis3 = rnorm(45, .5, .15),
                  stim_IVis4 = rnorm(45, .51, .125))

head(df1)
summary(df1)
```

To use `ez`, it's a pretty straightforward implementation. Although, I couldn't find an option that allowed for multiple dependent variables. Essentially, you would either need to `pivot_long` or you can use `jmv`.
For this method, you don't get the post hoc comparisons; the effect size is the generalized η<sup>2</sup>.

```
ezANOVA(df1, dv = stim_IVis3, wid = subject, within = time, 
        between = group, detailed = T)

# $ANOVA
#        Effect DFn DFd         SSn       SSd           F            p p<.05        ges
# 1 (Intercept)   1  12 12.58700023 0.3872673 390.0252306 1.616255e-10     * 0.92579702
# 2       group   2  12  0.05853169 0.3872673   0.9068417 4.297644e-01       0.05483656
# 3        time   2  24  0.05417372 0.6215855   1.0458491 3.668654e-01       0.05096178
# 4  group:time   4  24  0.06774352 0.6215855   0.6539102 6.298074e-01       0.06292379
# 
# $`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
#       Effect         W         p p<.05
# 3       time 0.9914977 0.9541232      
# 4 group:time 0.9914977 0.9541232      
# 
# $`Sphericity Corrections`
#       Effect       GGe     p[GG] p[GG]<.05      HFe     p[HF] p[HF]<.05
# 3       time 0.9915694 0.3664558           1.187039 0.3668654          
# 4 group:time 0.9915694 0.6286444           1.187039 0.6298074
```

Now to use `jmv`, you will need to pivot the data wider. Your within-subject data needs to be in separate columns. Since `time` is the factor that represents with the within-subject values in the `stim`... columns, that's what you need to pivot.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(subject, group),
              names_from = time,
              values_from = starts_with("stim"),
              names_vary = "fastest")

head(df2)
# # A tibble: 6 × 8
#   subject group stim_IVis3_1 stim_IVis3_2 stim_IVis3_3 stim_IVis4_1 stim_IVis4_2 stim_IVis4_3
#   <fct>   <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 1       1            0.497        0.505        0.601        0.417        0.776        0.660
# 2 2       1            0.584        0.408        0.737        0.454        0.670        0.650
# 3 3       1            0.741        0.399        0.450        0.306        0.665        0.577
# 4 4       1            0.223        0.450        0.350        0.522        0.342        0.417
# 5 5       1            0.717        0.661        0.581        0.601        0.700        0.686
# 6 6       2            0.534        0.780        0.443        0.420        0.565        0.739
```

Now you're ready for `jmv`. `bs` equates to between-subjects; `rm` equates to repeated measures.

```
fit = anovaRM(data = df2, 
              ss = "3",                                # type of SS (1, 2, or 3)
              bs = list("group"),                      # between subjects (links with other parameters this way)
              bsTerms = list("group"),
              rm = list(list(label = "stim_IVs",          # within subjects
                             levels = c(names(df2)[3:8]))), # could also write c("stim_IVs3_1", "stim_IVs3_2", "stim_IVs3_3")
              rmCells = list(list(measure = names(df2)[3], # could also write "stim_IVs3_1"
                                  cell = names(df2)[3]),   # the group associated in 'rm' level (I used the column name)
                             list(measure = names(df2)[4],     
                                  cell = names(df2)[4]),
                             list(measure = names(df2)[5],
                                  cell = names(df2)[5]),
                             list(measure = names(df2)[6],
                                  cell = names(df2)[6]),
                             list(measure = names(df2)[7],
                                  cell = names(df2)[7]),
                             list(measure = names(df2)[8],
                                  cell = names(df2)[8])
                             ),    
              rmTerms = list("stim_IVs"),         # groups variable for repeated/within measures
              emMeans = list(list("stim_IVs", "group")),  # all grouping vars in the ANOVA (for the em tables)
              emmPlots = T,                  # show em plots
              emmTables = T,                 # show em tables
              effectSize = c("omega", "partEta"), # multiple options here, see help
              spherTests = T,                # use correction
              spherCorr = c("none", "GG", "HF"),  # multiple options here, see help
              leveneTest = T,                # check homogeneity (p GREATER than .05 is good)
              qq = T,                        # plot normality validation qq plot
              postHoc = list("group",c("group","stim_IVs"),"stim_IVs"),
              postHocCorr = "tukey")         # use TukeyHSD
```

If you print `fit`, you're going to get a *ton* of information. In addition to the content provided by `ezANOVA`, this provides the post hoc comparisons of each group, time, dependent variable, and the intermix of each; the results of the statistical assumptions: Levene's for homogeneity and a QQ plot of the residuals for normality; and the estimated marginal means table and a plot of those means.

I realize that you have more fields in your data than what I have here. I believe I've provided enough for you to build off of.

I suggest that you determine what you want to learn from the data and choose the algorithm from there.

If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation and tips!